# How to make a JLabel word.wrap in a JList custom renderer?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, word-wrap, listcellrenderer

As the title says, I am creating a JList with a custom renderer.

The renderer simply adds a JPanel and puts a JLabel inside.

I am trying the "MY TEXT" trick on the JLabel, but it still refuses to word-wrap.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: I am not looking to hard-code any sizes. The text should wrap depending on the size of the window (which the user of course can resize at any time).

Main "ListTest2" class:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class ListTest2 extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ListTest2();
}

public ListTest2() {

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("JList Renderer Example");
    this.setSize(700, 500);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    listModel.addElement("USA");

    JList<String> countryList = new JList<>(listModel);
    countryList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    countryList.setCellRenderer(new CountryRenderer());        

    add(new JScrollPane(countryList));

    this.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Renderer class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class CountryRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<String> {

public CountryRenderer() {

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));

    JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("<html>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</html>");
    add(testLabel);

}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends String> list, String value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    return this;
}

}
```

Comment: JList might have a hardcoded height size of cells which is blocking your wrap.

Comment: Use a JTextArea instead of a JLabel if you want word wrapping.